# Fetching the data from the database by comparing email using angularjs and sql

Tags: php, sql, angularjs, json

I'm fetching data from database by comparing email but the code which I have written it is getting only one record if there are more than one record for that email.

```
$res="SELECT *  FROM user_salary_details  WHERE email ='$userEmailid '";
$result=mysql_query($res);  

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $city=$row["city"];
     $state=$row["state"];
     $pin=$row["pincode"];

     $data = array(
                    "success"   =>  "success",
                 "city"         => $city,
                 "state"        => $state,
                 "pin"          =>$pin,
              );

    echo json_encode($data);         
}
```

Comment: change the if to while

Comment: besides to use it this way add a param mysql_fetch_array($result , MYSQL_ASSOC) or use the function mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: if i write while it is not retriving the data getting alert as error while retriving the data

Comment: Not getting what you are saying

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: No it is not working getting only city that too only one

Comment: what does the var_dump[$row] return if you place it in the while loop?

Comment: but i didnt add var_dump any where in my code

Comment: Yep and i want you to do so and tell me what does it return : )

Comment: getting error occured while retriving data.Internal Server Error

Comment: You should use `mysqli_*` instead, `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: @Ties ok i will be using mysqli from now

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
// YOU FORGOT TO CONNECT
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM user_salary_details WHERE email='$userEmailid '";

// YOU NEED TO PASS CONNECTION AS FIRST ARGUMENT    
if(!$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){ // Use mysqli
    die 'Query Error'; // Exit script on error
}

$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // Loop trough all rows

     $rowData = $row;
     $rowData['success'] = 'success';
     $rowData['pin'] = $row['pincode'];
     unset $rowData['pincode'];

     $data[] = $rowData; // Add row to total data       
}
echo json_encode($data); // echo all data
```

Comment: You are using $rowData['pin'] = $row['pincode']; Which one is table name and which is another

Comment: No it is not working getting same issue as above internal server error status::500

Comment: As i gave connection at the begging only

Comment: Add `error_reporting( E_ALL );` on top of you PHP and check for errors